# What kind of format / language this is O:8:"stdClass":5: ? ( xml , json ) need to extract the value in python.

Tags: python

Here's the value :

```
   O:8:"stdClass":5:
{s:11:"origination";O:8:"stdClass":2:
    {s:8:"username";s:9:"Prod";s:8:"password";s:8:"vi5";}
    s:9:"serviceId";s:10:"9202501358";s:8:"elements";a:1:
    {i:0;s:4:"3260";}s:11:"serviceKeys";a:6:
    {i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1;s:5:"value";s:10:"2102799679";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1395;s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1390;s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:3;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1391;s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:4;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1392;s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:5;O:8:"stdClass":2:
        {s:2:"id";i:1393;s:5:"value";s:0:"";}}s:7:"transId";s:1:"1";}
```

I'm trying to extract its value that store in **mysql** for variable named "**data**" ,

i'm not sure if this is json , but for json it would be something like .. without "**;**"

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

How can I extract this  using python? I normally see xml where I used xpath :  `etree.XPath` to help extracting the value , But this format is new to me. couldn't figure it out where to start. Some recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried asking whoever gave you that data? (I removed the irrelevant tags since this doesn't even resemble JSON or XML in any way...)

Comment: Playing 'guess the data format' does not make great questions on Stack Overflow. I can tell you it is not JSON, nor is it XML though.

Comment: ...anyhow, your best bet for deserializing this will actually be to write a PHP program to convert it to JSON, and call and load *that* from Python.

Comment: I think that this question is on-topic on StackOverflow. Despite formatting, I can see no reason for so many downvotes.

Comment: I agree with @cubuspl42. Even if there is no "real" code behind it I hardly see how someone not familiar with the originating programming langage could guess it without asking for help, especially if the coder who did that is not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a serialized PHP object.
Example:

```
<?php                    
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->coin = 'coin';
$obj->num = 1;
var_dump(serialize($obj)); ?>
```

gives:

```
string(55) "O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"coin";s:4:"coin";s:3:"num";i:1;}"
```

Comment: Thank you ! this give me what to start with.